# Magento blank/empty (anchor) category page

Tags: magento

As the title describes my Magento store is showing blank category pages. I have the following error output:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in /app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php on line 411
Warning: include(Mage.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
Warning: include(Mage.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mage.php' for inclusion (include_path='app/code/local:app/code/community:/app/code/core:/lib:.') in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 244
Warning: include(Mage.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
Warning: include(Mage.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mage.php' for inclusion (include_path='app/code/local:app/code/community:/app/code/core:/lib:.') in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php on line 108
```

Calculation.php - Line 8 is line 411

```
    protected function _getRates($request, $fieldName, $type)
    {
        $result = array();
        $classes = Mage::getModel('tax/class')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('class_type', $type)
            ->load();
        foreach ($classes as $class) {
            $request->setData($fieldName, $class->getId());
            $result[$class->getId()] = $this->getRate($request);
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Autoload.php - Line 13 is line 94

```
    public function autoload($class)
    {
        if ($this->_collectClasses) {
            $this->_arrLoadedClasses[self::$_scope][] = $class;
        }
        if ($this->_isIncludePathDefined) {
            $classFile =  COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class;
        } else {
            $classFile = str_replace(' ', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $class)));
        }
        $classFile.= '.php';
        //echo $classFile;die();
        return include $classFile;
    }
```

Functions.php - Line 2 is line 244

```
 $errorMessage .= ": {$errstr}  in {$errfile} on line {$errline}";
    if (Mage::getIsDeveloperMode()) {
        throw new Exception($errorMessage);
    } else {
        Mage::log($errorMessage, Zend_Log::ERR);
    }
```

Session.php - Line 2 is line 108

```
        if (is_null($this->_lifeTime)) {
            $configNode = Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin() ?
                    'admin/security/session_cookie_lifetime' : 'web/cookie/cookie_lifetime';
            $this->_lifeTime = (int) Mage::getStoreConfig($configNode);
```

** UPDATE **

I just found out when I removed the 4th line the category pages will show up. But (logically) without layered nav.

```
  <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
```

Catalog/layer/view.phtml is look like this:

```
<?php if($this->canShowBlock()): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-content">
        <?php echo $this->getStateHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
            <div class="actions"><a href="<?php echo $this->getClearUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Clear All') ?></a></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($this->canShowOptions()): ?>
            <dl id="narrow-by-list">
                <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
                <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function($){
                    $(".block-layered-nav dt").click(function(){
                        if($(this).next("dd").css("display") == "none"){
                            $(this).next("dd").slideDown(200);
                            $(this).removeClass("closed");
                        } else {
                            $(this).next("dd").slideUp(200);
                            $(this).addClass("closed");
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I can still not find the issue on this.

--

I hope someone can help me out solving this issue.

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Thanks! I have posted the codes in the question.

Comment: Just indent the code (don't use a code snippet). Code snippets are only for HTML/CSS/Javascript. :)

Comment: The Autoloader is failing. The only reason that the Autoloader would work on the rest of the controller/model/view load but NOT your category load specifically would be an improper call to the Magento API from within the application. Post your code and we can help.

Comment: Hi @NickM thanks for your comment. I don't really understand you which code you want me to post. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check if app/Mage.php exists. Also check it's permissions.
Create new file in the root with the following code:

```
require_once("app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app();

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::init();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I just discovered only anchor categories are blank.

Comment: my code isn't working? what about Mage.php file existing and its permissions?

Comment: Nope, I added your code to index.php. Mage.php existed and to be sure I chanced the permissions to 777, default was 644.

Comment: this code shouldn't upload anything. This code can only cause errors. If everything is alright - you should see blank screen. Atm I have no ideas what has happened.